# How to add an img attribute to its surrounding div element

Tags: jquery, attributes

All images on my site are wrapped into divs, so I can add a mask for the image hover effect on top of them. Now I need to add the width of the image to its surrounding div.

Thats my HTML:

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
  <a href="/abc.php">
    <div class="imagebackicon"></div> <!-- ignore, its only for the image mask -->
    <div class="imagebackground"></div> <!-- ignore, its only for the image mask -->
    <img src="image.jpg" width="300" height="200" />
  </a>
</div>
```

I want to add the image width of "300" to its surrounding div. I accomplish this by doing:

```
$('.imagecontainer').width($(".imagecontainer").find('img').attr("width"));
```

The problem is, that this code adds the width of the first image to all of my surrounding image divs. Which is fine as long as all image have the same size, but they dont.

It would be great if anyone knows how i can add the image width only to its surrounding div, not to all image divs.

Comment: you want to add width on hover ?

Comment: no, I handle the hover with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this to all the images / containers, you'll need to iterate :

```
$('img').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(elem).closest('.imagecontainer').width($(elem).attr('width'));
});
```

or the other way around:

```
$('.imagecontainer').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(this).width( $(this).find('img').attr('width') );
});
```

Comment: Works perfect! You saved me a lot of trial and error time. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: What is the purpose of (i, elem)? Cause i used the function() without the "i, elem" and it works the same.

Comment: Those are just parameters of the each() function, the first being the index, and the second is the element. `this` would be the same as elem inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

a different approach would be ta apply the width to the container `div` in the first place, using an array of the corresponding values, and set `img` to `width:100%;`

JS:

```
var img = [100,300,200,600]; 
$(".imagecontainer").each(function(i){
$(this).width(img[i]);
});
```

(If the divs are dynamically generated on the server-side with a loop, you may consider using inline styling instead to set the container width on the HTML received from the server)

CSS:

```
img {
    width:100%;
}
```